# Windows MySQL Connection String: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I am running a classic ASP website which is running on IIS and is linked to a MySQL database version 5.0.19-log.

I often get this error on my site:

**[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.0.19-log]Lost connection to MySQL server during query**

As in, many times a day.

I connect to MySQL using classic ASP, via this string:

```
''----------------------
''connection string
''----------------------

Dim oConn
set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=[myserver];Database=[myDB];User=[user]; Password=[pwd];Option=3;"
```

I have swapped out actual data with the labels in square brackets.

Does anyone know if performance would be better using a System DSN instead, e.g.

```
''----------------------
''connection string
''----------------------

Dim oConn
set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "DSN=[DSN]; UID=[user]; PWD=[pwd];"
```

My host is having trouble getting the DSN to work, so I can't just test it.

The site gets between 400 and 600,000 page views per month, so maybe it is just too busy for MySQL or the MySQL / Windows driver to cope with? I'm not very technical, so don't know if it should be able to cope with that volume or not.

Traffic is limited to many page views, and lots of small queries, rather than processing a few big statements.

I have tried optimising the code etc.

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: MyODBC 3.51 is an old version of the driver.  5.1 is the current version.  It may not make any difference but you could ask your host if it is (or could be) installed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting/altering values for vars wait_timeout and max_allowed_packet?  You can set these on the server in the my.ini (instructions in comments in this file) or in the connection string.  Also you might look at connection pooling.